# Pegar retorno de autocomplete e colocar em inputs diferentes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $().ready(function() {
          $("#course").autocomplete("teste1.php", {
              width: 260,
              matchContains: true,
              selectFirst: false
      });
    });
</script>
```

Que pega o retorno daqui:

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

list($resultados,$quantidade) = $select->selectTable('f_tb_empresas','id_empresa,nm_empresa',NULL,"nm_empresa LIKE '%".$q."%'",NULL); 

foreach ($resultados as $row) {
    $linha['value'] = $row['nm_empresa'];
    $linha['id'] = $row['id_empresa'];

}

echo json_encode($linha);
```

E o resultado vem para o `input`:

```
<input type="text" name="course" id="course" />
```

O resultado vem assim: `{"value":"Alameda dos anjos","id":"39"}`
, mas queria que o id fosse para um input e o value para outro.

Como faço isso com JQuery?

Obrigada

Comment: o valor de $q está sendo passado diretamente para a query sem tratamento antes? >.<

Comment: @RenatoTavares por enquanto sim

Comment: Onde está o JS que retorna o JSON ?

Comment: @TaoPaiPai Essa é minha dúvida, como retorno esse valor? porque da forma como está no código o source vai direto pro input course

Comment: Esse script que tem a função `autocomplete`, tem o LINK ?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.autocomplete.css" />` @TaoPaiPai

Comment: Sim, mas você tem o LINK da documentação desse `jquery.autocomplete.js` ? Se não tiver, tudo bem. Só me explica uma coisa... você disse que quer o `value` em um `input` e o `id` em outro `input`. Em qual momento que você quer isso ? Quando retorna os dados ou quando você escolhe uma opção ? Caso seja a primeira opção não tem que ser os dois no mesmo `input` ?

Comment: @TaoPaiPai quando eu escolho uma opção, gostaria que o um input recebesse o value e o outro o id

Comment: Entendi, para isso você tem que ver os elementos que ele gera embaixo do `input`. Abre o Inspect Element do Chrome e digita algo no campo para rodar o `autocomplete`. No resultado que aparecer clique com o botão direito em cima de um resultado e vai em Inspecionar Elemento. Coloca um print no seu post do que aparece.

Comment: @TaoPaiPai link da imagem: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwH8KrvYWlojV3JSbkN3d2pHbU0/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo usar o jQuery UI, pois esse arquivo jquery.autocomplete.js é uma versão desatualizada da função.

Você pode conseguir os valores separados seguindo este exemplo:

```
$("#course").autocomplete("teste1.php", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "#campoNome" ).val( ui.item.label );
       $( "#campoValor" ).val( ui.item.value );    
    }
});
```

Dê uma olhada na documentação:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data